# Is `with return .. return` unreachable code?

Tags: python, pycharm, with-statement, contextmanager

PyCharm warns about this code, saying the last return is unreachable:

```
def foo():
    with open(...):
        return 1
    return 0
```

I expect that the second return would execute if `open()` failed. Who's right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

PyCharm is right. If `open()` fails, an exception is raised, and *neither* `return` is reached.

`with` does not somehow protect you from an exception in the expression that produces the context manager. The expression after `with` is expected to produce a context manager, at which point it's `__exit__` method is stored and it's `__enter__` method is called. The only outcomes here are that either the context manager is successfully produced and entered, or an exception is raised. At no point will `with` swallow an exception at this stage and silently skip the block.

Comment: Is that true of all context managers? If you write a custom one that does swallow the exception (replacing open in this case), it would reach the second return, wouldn't it? (Ran into this in some code I was modifying and was also confused by the linter's indication.)

Comment: @NathanielFord: it is true of all expressions that *yield* a context manager. `open()` is a function call, the result of the call is a context manager. That call could produce an exception instead of returning something. That's the issue here; before a context manager has been created, exceptions can still take place.

Comment: @NathanielFord: so if you replace `open()` with something that'll **always** return a context manager, and never raise an exception, then you can force the issue. But if your replacement still opens a file object, you'd still have to handle exceptions in that stage.

Comment: Got it! Thanks.